# Django sqlmigrate not showing raw sql

Tags: python, django

I tried to get the raw sql from Django migrate file.

I took the following steps:

$ python manage.py makemigrations

$ python manage.py sqlmigrate app_name 0001

and raw sql command should display, but the result only contains:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model User
--
--
-- Create model Config
--
COMMIT;
```

How to get the raw sql from sqlmigrate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read the source code of sqlmigrate and found that add DB name for migrate may work.

So the working version would be:

$ python manage.py sqlmigrate app_name 0001 --database=db_name

The source code is here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [sqlmigrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate) it will only print in a non-raw SQL format; it will not print it in raw as you expect. You can though use the following method to get all the raw SQL that Django has executed.

[Django-extensions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate) have a command [shell_plus](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/shell_plus.html) with a parameter `print-sql`

```
./manage.py shell_plus --print-sql
```

In django-shell all executed queries will be printed

For example:

```
User.objects.get(pk=1)
SELECT "auth_user"."id",
       "auth_user"."password",
       "auth_user"."last_login",
FROM "auth_user"
WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1

Execution time: 0.002466s [Database: default]

<User: username>
```

Comment: sqlmigrate works sometimes, not always. I am wondering when it will show raw sql. Is it related to Django version? I want the sql from migrate, not from running my application. I guess your solution can only show sql when running the application, right?

Comment: I see. if you can try and use the extension that I provided which will do exactly the same job accurately. If you do want to see why sqlmigrate is not working then update you question with cases for where it gives rawsql and non-rawsql. I would just recommend using the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with multiple databases and routers, my issue was the same - sqlmigrate only printing 'Creating Model XXX' and not SQL - adding the --database="db_name_from_settings_file" made it work (django 3.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue today (or so I thought). In my case, it turned out that I had a number of AlterField changes in my migration that didn't require any underlying changes to the Database. I initially assumed that sqlmigrate wasn't showing me the raw SQL, but after reading [For some migrations, why `sqlmigrate` shows empty, or the same SQL both directions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659454/for-some-migrations-why-sqlmigrate-shows-empty-or-the-same-sql-both-directio), I realized that in my case, there wasn't any raw SQL to show.